# Moles and chemical equations

Tags: mole

Sulfur reacts with oxygen according to the following equation:
2S + 3O2 -----> 2SO3
If 4 moles of sulphur reacts with 9.5 moles of oxygen, how many moles of oxygen would remain after the reaction?

Answer (score 1):

This a very logical question based on limiting reagent concept.

As you can see $2$ moles of sulfur require $3$ moles of $O_2$.
By unitary method $4$ moles of sulfur will require $6$ moles of $O_2$.
Hence $3.5$ moles of $O_2 $ will be left out.

By the way you shouldn't post such "homework" questions without showing any effort.

Comment: Posting homework is fine, but we expect to see some kind of effort before we provide help.